# make the text change according to the specified second with Jquery

Tags: jquery

how to make the text change according to the specified second, for example if in the 5th second will display the text "hello". in the 10th second display the image, and so on

```
var timer = 30;
if (timer == 5) {
  $(".messages").text("hello");
} else if (timer == 10) {
  $(".messages").html("<img src='img/image.jpg'>");
}
```

Comment: Hey @vhlan - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) ***to close out the question***. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). Remember, too: you can upvote any answers you found helpful (you can also upvote and checkmark the same answer, if desired.) *Thanks!*

Comment: This question is still open. Please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

You need either a setTimeout or a setInterval loop. Something like the below example.

In the example, the timer/counter works via the `setTimeout()` -- the `,500` part tells it to wait 500ms and then run again. To make it one-second intervals, change that to `,1000`

```js
let timer = 0;
do_test(timer);

function do_test(timer){
  timer++;
  if (timer > 29){
    $('body').css('background','blue');
  }else if (timer > 20){
    $('body').css('background','green');
  }else if (timer > 10){
    $('body').css('background','pink');
  }else if (timer > 3){
    $('body').css('background','yellow');
  }
  $('#cnt').text(timer);
  if (timer < 40){
    setTimeout(() => {do_test(timer)},500);
  } else {
    $('body').html('<div id="dun">DONE</div>');
  }
}
```

```css
#cnt{
  font-size:3rem;
  color: gold;
}
#dun{
  font-size: 9rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cnt"></div>
```

Comment: how to add fadein and fadeout at every change of text?

Comment: how to add fadein and fadeout at every change of text?

Comment: I don't know what you want to see happen.  Can you be more specific?  TBH, I suggest that you **choose a correct answer** for this question (to close the question) and then **create a new question** where you ask the next part of your question.  Why? **Two reasons:** (a) Right now I am probably the only person reading updates to this question, (b) You need to **explain what you want in more detail**. The best way to do that is with a new question - then thousands of people will read the new question and be able to help.

Comment: Note: Use the code example that I provided to create the code example in your new question.  Be Very Specific about what you want to see happen (don't make the reader guess - he won't. He'll leave.)